# SetInterval wont work? button still has to be pressed each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, setinterval

I need the images to change from one to another each time the button is pressed. I have tried using SetTimeout, setInterval etc and none of these seem to work? Im not sure what I'm doing wrong

```js
var list = [
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe1940f0b6156700004d/traffic-light-red.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe3e40f0b6156700004f/traffic-light-green.jpg",
  "http://thndl.com/images/1_3.png"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == list.length) 
    index = 0;
  
  var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    ChangeLights()
  }, 1000);
}

}();
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

Comment: JS is case sensitive, `ChangeLights()` != `changeLights()`. Also note that you can give `setInterval` the function reference directly, like this: `var myVar = setInterval(changeLights, 1000);`

Comment: [Looking at the browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) would have immediately told what the problem is.

Comment: you define `list`, but don't do anything with it. also, I see no definition of `ChangeLights`

Comment: Also note that your logic is flawed as your code will exponentially create new timers every second, so will most likely crash the browser after a few seconds. I would suggest you move the `setInterval()` outside of `changeLights()`

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ChangeLights` instead of `changeLights`. But even if you call it right, you create an interval with calling the same function each 1000 ms. That means at the second call, it create a new interval and calls it again and the actual interval call the function as well.

Solution: Separate initializing of the interval and the function for doing the work.

Start with `startLights` and call `changeLights` in the interval.

```js
var list = [
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe1940f0b6156700004d/traffic-light-red.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe3e40f0b6156700004f/traffic-light-green.jpg",
  "http://thndl.com/images/1_3.png"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
    index = index + 1;
    if (index == list.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    console.log(index);
}

function startLights() {
    setInterval(changeLights, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="startLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

1. `changeLights() != ChangeLights()`

**Warning**

2. Is the `setInterval()` placing

Not apply the `setInterval()` inside the click function.In each time loop time second's are reduced.so its change more lower time seconds.So use with setInterval with in click and color `change` was separate

```js
var list = [
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe1940f0b6156700004d/traffic-light-red.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe3e40f0b6156700004f/traffic-light-green.jpg",
  "http://thndl.com/images/1_3.png"
];

var index = 0;

function change() {
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == list.length) 
    index = 0;
  console.log(list[index])
 
}
function changeLights(){
 var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    change()
  }, 1000);
  }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As above answers indicate - the call to the function needs to be outside it. One alteration I would suggest is to use the modulus operator (index % 3) which will allow a constant cycling of the images without the need for the if statement. This works because the modulus operator gives the remainder after dividing the number by the operator - so modulus %3 will mean that for example if index is three - the remainder is 0, 4 gives 1 5 gives 2 and then 6 is back at 0. So you have a perfect cycling count giving the three values 0,1, and 2 without having to check for each one.

```js
var list = [
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe1940f0b6156700004d/traffic-light-red.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe48ed915d1592000048/traffic-light-amber.jpg",
  "https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/559fbe3e40f0b6156700004f/traffic-light-green.jpg",
  "http://thndl.com/images/1_3.png"
];

var index = 0;

function changeLights() {
  index +=1;
  document.getElementById('imageSrc').textContent = 'Source: ' + list[index %3];
  document.getElementById('lights').src = list[index %3];
}

  var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    changeLights()
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="imageSrc"></p>
<img id = "lights"/>
```